# Unable to add post in firestore using react-admin-firebase data provider package

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-admin

I was trying to connect my react-admin front end to firebase to perform crud operations.
I have used [react-admin-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-admin-firebase) package as a data provider, It is working fine for reading operations but while creating posts it is showing (Server communication error) as an error on the screen and `{status: 200, message: '', json: undefined} json: undefined message: "" status: 200 [[Prototype]]: Object`
on console.

App.js file

```js
import React from "react"
import { Admin, Resource } from "react-admin"
import PostList from "./components/PostList"
import PostCreate from "./components/PostCreate"
import PostEdit from "./components/PostEdit"
import PostShow from "./components/Show"
import MyPostList from "./components/MyPosts"
import Grid from "./Grid";
import {
  FirebaseDataProvider,
  FirebaseRealTimeSaga
} from 'react-admin-firebase';

const config = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
  appId: "xxxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxx"
};

const options = {};
const dataProvider = FirebaseDataProvider(config, options);

function App() {
  return (
    <Admin
      dataProvider={dataProvider}
    >
      <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} create={PostCreate} show={PostShow} edit={PostEdit} />
      <Resource name="myposts" list={MyPostList} create={PostCreate} show={PostShow} edit={PostEdit} />
      <Resource name="gridView" list={Grid} create={PostCreate} show={PostShow} edit={PostEdit}/> 
    </Admin>
  )
}

export default App
```

and PostCreate.js file

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {Create, SimpleForm, TextInput, DateInput, required } from 'react-admin';
import RichTextInput from 'ra-input-rich-text';

const phoneNumberFormat = (num) => {
     let x;
    if (typeof num !== "undefined") {
          
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^[0-9\b]+$/);
        if (!pattern.test(num)) {

          x= "Please enter only number.";
        }else if(num.length != 10){
          x= "Please enter valid phone number.";
        }
      }
    return x;
};
const validatePhone = [required("Phone number is required"), phoneNumberFormat];

const BodyWordLimit = (num) => {
    let x;
    if(num.length>1000)
    {
        x="You can write only 1000 characters in Description";
    }
   return x;
};
const validateBody = [required("Discription is required"), BodyWordLimit];

const TitleWordLimit = (num) => {
    let x;
    if(num.length>255)
    {
        x="You can write only 255 characters in Title";
    }
   return x;
};
const validateTitle = [required("Title is required"), TitleWordLimit];

const PostCreate = (props) => {
    
    return (
        <Create title='Create a Post' {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput source="title" validate={validateTitle}/>
            <RichTextInput multiline source="body" validate={validateBody}/>
            <DateInput label="Publication date" source="published_at" defaultValue={new Date()} />
            <TextInput source="phone" validate={validatePhone}  />

        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
    )
}
    
export default PostCreate
```

Can anyone help? I have been desperately looking for the fix for the past 2-3 days...

Comment: did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it adding the authProvider and set logging config to true.

I have no clue about why it behaves this way

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).